# Password Protection for Images on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, password-protection

I am planning to create an application which protects images from unauthorized access by anyone. What I'm planning to do is protect the images by putting a password in the image so that every time I view the image it will prompt to input first the password assigned. How can I do this? or is it possible?

Comment: It might be more effective to use the password as a key to encrypt the image.  That way, it's harder to write a program that simply skips your password and reads the image data.

Comment: Also it might be better to password protect the location containing the images, it may be annoying to be asked for the password 5-6 times in a row if i protected more than 1 image...

Comment: @walkingTarget: I think it might be better if the password will be the key to encrypt the image. But, do you have any idea on how ti implement it? Thanks

Comment: What is the question exactly? How to encrypt and decrypt data with a password in Java?

Comment: You would use something like the Data Encryption Standard.  If memory serves, the algorithm uses the shared key to encrypt something else. I bet there's an encryption library in Java that takes a key and a length of bytes and returns encrypted bytes. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find a way to store a password somewhere in the data of an image file, but you cannot force the consumers of that image file to enter a password or otherwise restrict access to the image from the image itself.  Images aren't programs.

@walkingTarget's comment would be the best way to universally restrict access to the image -- encrypt the image file using some user-definable key.  Your question then becomes "how do I encrypt/decrypt files in Java on the Android platform?"  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866457/solved-why-is-desktop-aes-file-io-incompatible-with-android-aes-file-io) might nudge you toward an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use zip with password to encrypt the image and then use android to open it by prompting the user to give password